# Which Rails files are parsed through ERB first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions, erb

I was looking through a new default Rails application, and in `config/database.yml` I noticed a snippet of ERB:

```
...

default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %> # <-- ERB
  timeout: 5000

...
```

Now, I know what ERB is and how it works. What I'm confused by is the fact that the fact a file contains ERB is usually indicated in the file name. For example, a view file might be called `index.html.erb`.

It's a sort of trivial point, and it might be that the answer is "they just didn't feel like it, it's their package", but why isn't this file called (say) `database.yml.erb`? The name as it stands suggests it should just contain plain YAML, and it doesn't.

Comment: One reason I can think of is that changing the file name will disable yml syntax in most editors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a special case. At some point the strategy outlined http://urgetopunt.com/2009/09/12/yaml-config-with-erb.html became the default. I tried to find where in GitHub, but didn't find the exact date of when this happened.

Comment: It's one of those things that's been there since very early versions of Rails, possibly 1.0.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if this the case for all `.yml` files in Rails, just some, or more types than just YAML?

Comment: Its a limited number of cases limited to configuration like database.yml and secrets and anything loaded with `Rails.application.configuration_for`.